# Saving array text content in an created csv file in actionscript 3.0

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, csv, savechanges

im having problems on how to save the content of an array in an csv file that already has a content. its like overwriting the content of the csv file. the array is like this (Array [1][1]). i've search and googled it but every answer i got is still wrong. Please im in a deadline right now... thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple way to do it is use csvlib. [Here is the short description](http://code.google.com/p/csvlib/)
of this library, and [here](http://code.google.com/p/csvlib/wiki/QuickStart)
is a few tutorials.

Probably it will be something like you reading data from csv file, modifying/adding something, and saving again.

Comment: do you have a much visual code that i can look for the saving part to csv file is much more appreciated